# How to access a value from a nested dictionary in Swift4?

Tags: ios, json, iphone, swift, dictionary

I want to get the value of **City:** in my json structure. I receive the data inside a Dictionary with **dictionary: [String : Any]?**

I already tried several methods but nothing worked for me. I think my problem is because auf the nested structure with the multiple { and [

```
{
"Format": "XXXXXXXXX",
"FormatVersion": "1.0",
"Status": "OK",
"NumToReturn": 1,
"AllResults": [
{
  "ConversationState": {
    "ConversationStateTime": XXXXXXXXX,
    "QueryEntities": {
      "Where": [
        {
          "Type": "City",
          "Label": "Stuttgart, Germany",
          "SpokenLabel": "Stuttgart",
          "Address": "Stuttgart, Baden-Wurttemberg, Germany",
          "City": "Stuttgart",
          "Admin2": "Regierungsbezirk Stuttgart",
          "Admin1": "Baden-Wurttemberg",
          "Country": "Germany",
          "CountryCode": "DE",
          "IATA": "STR",
          "Geohash": "u0wt8bd9854n",
          "Verified": true,
          "HighConfidence": true,
          "CurrentLocation": false,
          "Latitude": 48.78231811523438,
          "Longitude": 9.177020072937012,
          "ReferenceDatum": "WGS84",
          "TimeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
          "Radius": 10,
          "Links": [
            {
              "Label": "Wikipedia",
              "URL": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuttgart"
            }
          ],
          "TypeID": 5,
          "SourceID": 2,
          "RecordID": 2825297
        }
      ]
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: post your code, please

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

struct YourClass: Codable {
    let format, formatVersion, status: String
    let numToReturn: Int
    let allResults: [AllResult]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case format = "Format"
        case formatVersion = "FormatVersion"
        case status = "Status"
        case numToReturn = "NumToReturn"
        case allResults = "AllResults"
    }
}

struct AllResult: Codable {
    let conversationState: ConversationState

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case conversationState = "ConversationState"
    }
}

struct ConversationState: Codable {
    let conversationStateTime: String
    let queryEntities: QueryEntities

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case conversationStateTime = "ConversationStateTime"
        case queryEntities = "QueryEntities"
    }
}

struct QueryEntities: Codable {
    let queryEntitiesWhere: [Where]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case queryEntitiesWhere = "Where"
    }
}

struct Where: Codable {
    let type, label, spokenLabel, address: String
    let city, admin2, admin1, country: String
    let countryCode, iata, geohash: String
    let verified, highConfidence, currentLocation: Bool
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    let referenceDatum, timeZone: String
    let radius: Int
    let links: [Link]
    let typeID, sourceID, recordID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "Type"
        case label = "Label"
        case spokenLabel = "SpokenLabel"
        case address = "Address"
        case city = "City"
        case admin2 = "Admin2"
        case admin1 = "Admin1"
        case country = "Country"
        case countryCode = "CountryCode"
        case iata = "IATA"
        case geohash = "Geohash"
        case verified = "Verified"
        case highConfidence = "HighConfidence"
        case currentLocation = "CurrentLocation"
        case latitude = "Latitude"
        case longitude = "Longitude"
        case referenceDatum = "ReferenceDatum"
        case timeZone = "TimeZone"
        case radius = "Radius"
        case links = "Links"
        case typeID = "TypeID"
        case sourceID = "SourceID"
        case recordID = "RecordID"
    }
}

struct Link: Codable {
    let label: String
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case label = "Label"
        case url = "URL"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `JSON` is not example and you are using it, there is invalid JSON value in `ConversationStateTime`. Its value should be inside double quote unless it is an integer value.

`"ConversationStateTime": "XXXXXXXXX"`

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your JSON. "ConversationStateTime" doesn't have proper value
2. If its valid, please try this code to get "City" value from your JSON

   ```
   // response is your JSON

    func parseJSON() {
       let allResults = response!["AllResults"] as? NSArray

       for (_, element) in (allResults?.enumerated())! {
           let elementDict = element as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
           let conversationStateDict = elementDict!["ConversationState"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
           let queryDict = conversationStateDict!["QueryEntities"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
           let whereDict = queryDict!["Where"] as? NSArray

           for (_, whereDictElement) in (whereDict?.enumerated())! {
               let dict = whereDictElement as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
               print(dict!["City"])
           }
       }
   }
   ```